# search multi column and join another query when a condition is true

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-8

i want to search in posts table for a search query, i should search in title and slug columns, also i have a checkbox to search only published posts.

in my code my query always ignore is_publish query. how can i search on only published post when "search on published post" checkbox is checked?

```
    $query = Post::when($request->target, function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('title','LIKE', "%$request->target%")->orWhere('slug', 'like', "%$request->target%");
        })->when($request->publish, function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('is_publish', 1);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like as below:

```
$query = Post::when($request->target, function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->whereRaw("(title LIKE '%$request->target%' or slug LIKE '%$request->target%')")
})->when($request->publish, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('is_publish', 1);
});
```